# 24V failsafe switch that cuts power untill power is removed and reapplied

Tags: solenoid, 24v

Does anyone know of a device that when current is applied it will stay on for a certain period of time then turn off until current is removed and reapplied?

Basically I have a float switch that, when fluid gets low, it flips on 24v current which flips on a solenoid valve until the fluid fills up enough to turn the valve back off.  The problem is that if the fluid does not fill up enough of the valve sticks then the solenoid stays on and after a while gets extremely hot.  The fluid I am using gums up when under heat so the solenoid then becomes stuck and it is a HUGE mess to fix.  I am hoping that there is a simple device that I can put in line between the power so that after say 15 seconds it will cut the power until power is removed and reapplied again.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

Get a monostable (one-shot) timer relay - you apply power to the coil and the contacts close but open after a preset period: -

[image]

[Here's](http://uk.farnell.com/solid-state-relays_time-delay/timer-functions/single-shot/pg/110495970?CMP=KNC-GUK-FUK-GEN-KWL&gclid=CIr5mOzWjcACFSgFwwodKl0A5A) a link to Farnell that can sell you one but you'll probably find eBay will be cheaper.